# Export mysql dump file, such that statments are in the order of dependency

Tags: mysql, dump

I need to create a dump file such that when i execute it, i have no depency issues

1. tables run before queries
2. parent tables before child tables etc
3. no failed insert due to foreign key failures

Answer (score 1):

Two tables may refer each other with FK so not always possible to create and insert "parent first".

Use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) . It will disable foreign keys before importing data and enable afterward. (this is also much faster).